# Monitoring Geoserver for Production Environment

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, server

[image]Is there any opensource server monitoring is available for Geoserver ? Like watchdog and nagios?

Suppose if geoserver is stopped working whether mapmeter will automatically start it..Like the following image it should happen. Is it possible ?

Comment: The `check_postgres` script for Nagios / Icinga is useful, and can collect data to feed into Munin.

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting you. Can you be more specific ! ?

Comment: http://bucardo.org/wiki/Check_postgres, https://www.icinga.org/

Comment: Try this: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/monitoring/index.html but its not a central server... Good start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boundless has a product called Mapmeter, which can be used to monitor your Geoserver deployment. It has several [features](http://mapmeter.com/features.html) such as monitoring  Layer Usage, Service Usage, User Activity etc.

Here is a good page to help you [get started](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/mapmeter/getting-started-mapmeter/) with Mapmeter

Comment: I have updated my post !!